# Creating a dictionary with GroupBy and Sum as Key/Value

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have classes of Message such as

```
public class Message
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public ICollection<MessageProperty> Properties {get;set;}
}

public class MessageProperty
{
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

I would like a `Dictionary<string, int>` which has the Key as "Language", and a Value of sum of all messages where the language matches.

So I end up with `Key:"en-GB", Value:123`

I currently have a `IEnumerable<Message>` to work with to get the info out.

I know I will have to do a GroupBy and a Sum but all the things I've tried has not quite worked.

Could you show me how to get this dictionary? Thanks

**UPDATE:** Each Message in my Enumerable would like

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"test",
   "properties":[
      {
         "Key":"language",
         "Value":"en-gb"
      },
      {
         "Key":"gender",
         "Value":"male"
      },
      {
         "Key":"klout",
         "Value":10
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will select all the properties from all messages and then create a dictionary based on keys and count how many times each key occur

```
messages.SelectMany(message => message.Properties)
        .Where(prop => prop.Key == "language")
        .GroupBy(prop => prop.Value)
        .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key,
                      grp => grp.Count());
```

Comment: I need to check that the MessageProperty has the Key property value "Language"

Comment: Add sample data to your question and give expected behaviour